# Создание новых объектов на карте в границах имеющегося полигона

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Подскажите как можно ограничить рабочую область для создания новых объектов на карте имеющимся на ней полигоном (например как на скрине)? Чтобы можно было создавать новые геометрические фигуры лишь внутри этой области.

И есть ли возможность привязки Placemark'ов к ребрам?

[image: пример полигона]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По итогу сделал так:

- при создании нового Placemark проверяется просиходит обращение к методу getClosest геометрии полигона `polygon?.geometry?.getClosest(координаты новой точки)`
- и просто заменяю координаты только что созданноого Placemark на полученные из прошлого шага `placemark?.geometry?.setCoordinates(closes?.position);`

Это позволило присваивать меткам близжайшее к ним место на ребре полигона

---

Наверное, стоит отметить, что Placemark создаются пустыми и координаты помещаются в них только после нажатия на карту.